# When exchanging the Amazon Alexa grant_code for an access_token, where are the credentials?

Tags: oauth-2.0, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to write the exchange and access endpoints and the docs here (https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/linking-an-alexa-user-with-a-user-in-your-system#h2_login) are not clear on a couple of things:

1. how is the call to exchange a grant code for access token made - is it GET with credentials in QS or is it a POST with credentials in a body?
2. Is the access token delivered only in the JSON for an intent call or is it set properly as a bearer token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It's a `POST` with credentials in the request body. Amazon follows [the Oauth2 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.2) correctly in this case.
2. The access token is delivered by Amazon **only** in the JSON for the intent request and **not** properly set as a bearer. This is annoying.

In my case, I had to hack around it by first validating if the request was a valid alexa request which contained a session with an access token, then setting the `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` header to `Bearer <token>`, then using existing request auth logic to authenticate (I was using Django with django-oauth-toolkit, so YMMV if you're using something else).

That code looks something like this:

```
    # get the access_token from the POST request
    if access_token is not None:
        request.META["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"] = "Bearer " + access_token
        if not hasattr(request, 'user') or request.user.is_anonymous():
            user = authenticate(request=request)
            if user:
                request.user = request._cached_user = user

        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            # Do whatever with the logged in user
```

Comment: Thank you.  The docs were unhelpful on this one...I'm using NodeJS so will need to build custom validation for Alexa, which is fine, now I know how it works! (Also have to hack round the CSRF token!)

Comment: Yep, I had to hack around the the CSRF token as well. Good luck!

Comment: Hey Noah, I'm trying to use django-oauth-toolkit with Alexa skills kit too but I'm having a nightmare with it! Keeps saying "Unable to link __ skill, please try again later". I've just used the default endpoints that django-oauth-toolkit provided. Is there any tweaking necessary to make it work with Alexa Skills kit? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Hi @zubhav, yes, there's some tweaking necessary. Not sure how far along you are in the process. You need to make sure your web application has an Application registered correctly for your Alexa skill (i.e. you need to deploy your web app, then go into django admin, then make the new application model). From there, you'll need to copy the client id and client secret into your Alexa skill configuration, and do the hack that I noted in the answer with the token as well. To start debugging, I'd recommend looking at your production web app logs to make sure the OAuth requests are coming in.

Comment: Hi, I've done all of those steps with the default configuration settings of the OAuth toolkit. Not sure what could be going wrong, I'll check the requests on the server and get back to you... Thanks again!